functional iteration and convolution
Question
$$ H(u,t)= u^{-1} (u X-1+e^{-uX }) $$
$$ H_T(u)=sup H(u,t) $$
$$H_T(u e^{-a v} ) <H_T(u) $$
$$ H_T(u)< u c^{-2} +2c_1 A(c_1 u) + H_T(u e^{-a v})$$
the author iterates the above equation and gets
$$ H_T(u)< \frac{1}{2}  c^2 \cdot  u (1- e^{-a v} )^{-1} +2 c_1  \sum_{r=0} ^{n-1} A(c_1 u e^{-r a v} ) + H_T(u e^{-a n v}) $$
I guess the author uses the method of convolution.  But I don't know the explicit form of convolution.  How the author obtains the last equation?
My effort
$$\int e^{3x}(e^{4x}+7)~dx$$
$$\begin{align*} 
u & =e^{3x} & dv & =e^{4x}+7\\
du & =3e^{3x}dx & v & = \frac{1}{4}e^{4x}+7x
\end{align*}$$
which is
$$e^{3x}\left(\frac{1}{4}e^{4x}+7\right) - \int \left(\frac{1}{4}e^{4x}+7x\right)3e^{3x}~dx$$
$$E(x_0\exp((\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \mu B_t) = x_0\exp((\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t)E(\exp(\mu B_t))$$
$$X_t=x_0e^{(\mu-\sigma^2/2)t+\sigma B_t}$$
Hence
$$E(X_t)=x_0e^{(\mu-\sigma^2/2)t}E(e^{\sigma B_t})$$

...why did you deliberately make your question harder to read by moving it to a link?

This question is very complicated and long.     I am sorry.

To know the variance of $X_n$, all we need to know is that $X_n$ is $1$ with probability $p_n$ and $-1$ otherwise. Then $\mathbb E[X_n] = 2p_n - 1$ and $$\operatorname{Var}[X_n] = \mathbb E[X_n^2] - \mathbb E[X_n]^2 = 1 - \mathbb E[X_n]^2 = 1 - (2p_n - 1)^2,$$ as in the quoted text. (We get $\mathbb E[X_n^2] = 1$ because $X_n^2$ is actually always $1$.)

Thank you very much.  Why $\mathbb E[X_n^2] = 1$?

Because $1^2 = 1$ and $(-1)^2 = 1$.

That seems reasonable; we have $X_n = \delta_{ij} X_{n-1}$, so $X_{n-1} X_n = \delta_{ij} X_{n-1}^2 = \delta_{ij}$. Thus we just need $\mathbb E[\delta_{ij}]$, which simplifies to $2 \Pr[X_{n-1} = X_n] - 1$.

Thanks a lot.    I have a new question
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4977631/correlation-and-covariance-in-a-markov-chain
